# JSON-LD can't define multiple node types in @context

Tags: json-ld

The documentation of JSON-LD types clearly states that you can define multiple types to a node.
https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#specifying-the-type
If you open the example #14 from the above url in the [JSON-LD playground](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-expand&json-ld=%7B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%22%40id%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fme.markus-lanthaler.com%2F%22%2C%0A%20%20%22%40type%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FPerson%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2FPerson%22%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%7D), you will see that it is a valid syntax.

```
{
    "@id": "http://me.markus-lanthaler.com/",
    "@type": [
      "http://schema.org/Person",
      "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person"
    ]
}
```

However, if you try to move this definition into @context, and apply it to a specific property, you will get an error from the parser. Check it [here](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-expanded&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22some_property%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fme.markus-lanthaler.com%2F%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FPerson%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2FPerson%22%5D%7D%7D%2C%22some_property%22%3A%22value%22%7D&context=%7B%7D).

```
{
  "@context": {
    "some_property": {
      "@id": "http://me.markus-lanthaler.com/",
      "@type": [
        "http://schema.org/Person",
        "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person"
      ]
    }
  },
  "some_property": "value"
}
```

The error displayed is:
jsonld.SyntaxError: Invalid JSON-LD syntax; an @context @type value must be a string.

I read the documentation carefully and it says that you can define multiple types for node types, but not for value objects.
The [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#typed-values) clearly says that when @value and @type are used in the same dictionary, the @type keyword is expressing a value type. Otherwise, the @type keyword is expressing a node type.
But [here](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-expanded&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22some_property%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fme.markus-lanthaler.com%2F%22%7D%7D%2C%22some_property%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FPerson%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2FPerson%22%5D%2C%22%40value%22%3A%22value%22%7D%7D&context=%7B%7D) is another example showing that this might not be true.

Does anybody have an idea how to define multiple node types in @context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot, because you cannot define node types in a context at all.

Starting normatively. In https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#context-definitions we read:

> If the expanded term definition contains the @type keyword, its value MUST be an absolute IRI, a compact IRI, a term, null, or one of the keywords @id, @json, @none, or @vocab.

No arrays allowed here. Because `@type` in an expanded term definition in a context is used to specify the type of values of the defined property. As mentioned eg. in https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#typed-values:

> Typed values may be expressed in JSON-LD in three ways:
>
> 1. By utilizing the @type keyword when defining a term within an @context section.

Finally let's see what your example expands to if we correct it to have a string value for `@type`.

```
{
  "@context": {
    "some_property": {
      "@id": "http://me.markus-lanthaler.com/",
      "@type": "http://schema.org/Person"
    }
  },
  "some_property": "value"
}
```

expands to

```
[
  {
    "http://me.markus-lanthaler.com/": [
      {
        "@type": "http://schema.org/Person",
        "@value": "value"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

As you can see there you indeed have `@value` and `@type` together.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helps a lot.
However, what about the last issue I mentioned? If you check my last example in the post (Last url. I can't post it here because of character limit), you will see that in the expanded form, the **type** and **value** are on the same level, therefore **type** is the value type definition. But, as per [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#example-15-using-a-term-to-specify-the-type) (green comment under example), value type can have only one type and not two as in our example.

Comment: @papazulu Yes, interesting. If I uderstand it correctly, that last example is allowed as a _frame document_. I such documents a [value pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#value-patterns) can have a list of strings for its `@type`.